# Metaphor in Quran?

Tags: quran, maryam, surat-maryam

I read the verses 19:23 and 19:25 which says:

> And the pains of childbirth drove her to the trunk of a palm tree. She said, "Oh, I wish I had died before this and was in oblivion, forgotten."`

...

> And shake toward you the trunk of the palm tree; it will drop upon you ripe, fresh dates.

So Maryam is pregnant and she is in pain because of the pregnancy. And Allah gives her dates and water to "calm her down". But my question is: Are dates and water really that what a woman needs before giving a birth, full in pain? I mean Allah knows everything and is always doing the right. Is this verse just a metaphor?

Answer (score 2):

Dates have ingredients that are useful during the pregnancy and childbirth. Especially fresh dates رطب which have a higher content of ferreous, vitamine B and lower content of sugar than (dried) dates as mentioned in the qur'an. Which are some of the elements a pregnant woman may need during her pregnancy. 
See also [Is there advice on what a woman should do during pregnancy?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/435/is-there-advice-on-what-a-woman-should-do-during-pregnancy/29926#29926)